ValidationException: Invalid Model Identifier Error with Bedrock Runtime using boto3 in Python
I'm trying to use the AWS Bedrock Runtime service with boto3 to run inference on a language model. My code is attempting to call the converse method, but I'm encountering the following error:
ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Converse operation: The provided model identifier is invalid.

Here's a snippet of my code:
import boto3
import json

config = {
    "additionalModelRequestFields": {},
    "inferenceConfig": {
        "maxTokens": 512,
        "temperature": 0.5,
        "topP": 0.9
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "content": [
                {
                    "text": "How are you?"
                }
            ],
            "role": "user"
        }
    ]
}

body = json.dumps(config)

client = boto3.client('bedrock-runtime', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

model_id = 'meta.llama3-2-11b-instruct-v1'

response = client.converse(inferenceConfig=config['inferenceConfig'], messages=config['messages'], modelId=model_id)

I'm using the model ID meta.llama3-2-11b-instruct-v1, but the error message indicates that this model identifier might be incorrect.
Double-checked the model ID for typos.
Verified that the region is correct (us-east-1).
Checked the AWS documentation for Bedrock Runtime to ensure I'm using the correct parameters.

The model that you want to use - meta.llama3-2-11b-instruct-v1:0 can only be invoked with inference profile - us.meta.llama3-2-11b-instruct-v1:0.
model_id = 'us.meta.llama3-2-11b-instruct-v1:0'

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/cross-region-inference-support.html for details.

Looks like the issue was that the model id I was using is incorrect. It should have been meta.llama3-2-11b-instruct-v1:0. However, it looks like this specific model does not support this functionality
ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Converse operation: The provided model doesn't support on-demand throughput.

